# Heat map with categorical data

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I wish to create a heatmap like the one in the [Highmaps demo page](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/heatmap), but with categorical data:

Imagine a temporal dataset of a machine which can be in any one of the following states at some time: 'on', 'idle', 'off' and have a certain energy consumption value (e.g. 10Wh, 15Wh, 50Wh).

I want the heatmap do color each state of the machine with a different color:
'on': green
'idle': yellow
'off': gray

However, I also want that the lightness of the color corresponds to its energy consumption value, e.g. when the machine is in state 'idle' with energy consumption 1W is should be shown in a lighter shade of yellow than when it is in the same 'idle' state and energy consumption is '15W'.

How can this be achieved with highmaps/highcharts?

Comment: So in other words you want to have three colorAxes? One for "idle", one for "on" and one for "off"? I would try to display three series, each with different value-range (for example idle = multiply by 100, on = multiply by 1000 or something similar). Then as result you can get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LLto1wxv/2/ ?

Comment: @PawełFus something like this, but the values shown in the tooltip and label must be correct. I can work around the issue with the tooltips, but I don't know how correct the legend. Is it possible to display three legends?

Comment: Only one color-axis per chart is supported, that's why I used that workaround with values.

Comment: @PawełFus, thank you for the answer. OK, another acceptable option would to display a legend of just the categories, all the rest being the same:

'on': green
'idle': yellow
'off': gray

. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, simply remove `colorAxis`. Of course, without `colorAxis` colors won't be automatically set. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LLto1wxv/4/

Comment: @PawełFus, I wasn't sufficiently clear before. I meant to keep the range of color category on the chart (e.g. 'on' going from light to dark green, etc) - like here  jsfiddle.net/LLto1wxv/2, but the legend only showing 'on' -> green (without the range here) - like in your last example.

Comment: As I said before: without `colorAxis` colors won't be automatically set/tween.